# Recommendations for a taskbar/panel

Tags: software-recommendation, panel, taskbar

What taskbars/panels are available in Ubuntu ?

What process should I follow to configure them ?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?  I'm assuming 11.10 but it would be good to add that information.

Comment: Yes..its v11.10

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! There are many programs available that could be used to set up something like a taskbar. Can you edit your question to provide additional information on what desktop interface (Unity, GNOME Shell, etc.) you are using and what features you are looking for? This will help us make better recommendations. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, am new to Ubuntu and I am using it on Parallels on Mac by downloading from Ubuntu website. So I dont know the desktop (Unity, GNOME Shell, etc.) am using. Ho can I know, which desktop interface am using.

Comment: You can find a list of available desktop interfaces [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/65083/18612). If you didn't install any new ones or choose a different one from the login screen, then you are probably using Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Mine is Unity, but I would like to try GNOME Shell. Any suggestions, which one is the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a task-bar

Ctrl+Alt+t opens a terminal, then

```
sudo apt-get install tint2
```

[image]

[reference](http://linuxandfriends.com/2011/10/29/how-to-add-a-taskbar-in-ubuntu-11-10/)

[tint2 website](https://code.google.com/p/tint2/)

[Looking for cool configurations?](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=3232)

Comment: Why this program need terminal to be open?

Comment: for installation and set up

Answer (score 0):

### Lxpanel

---

Features:

- Lightweight
- Plugins
- Panel can be configured from GUI
- Generate a menu for installed applications automatically
- Can support multiple-panel layouts

[image]

To install the panel:

> sudo apt-get install lxpanel

[LXPanel website](http://lxde.org/lxpanel)

[Wiki Page](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXPanel)

---

### Xfce Panel:

---

Features

- program launchers
- panel menus
- desktop switcher and more
- Customizable plugins
- Can be configured through graphical dialogs,GTK+ style properties, and hidden Xfconf settings

[image]

To install the panel:

> sudo apt-get install xfce4-panel

[Xfce docs and plugins](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/start)